# Wildfly 23 starts... but then blocks because of startup timeout

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wildfly, maven-plugin, startup

It seems to start correctly

```
17:44:17,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
17:44:17,201 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8180
17:44:17,202 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8543
17:44:17,456 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\ActionICT-Motti\IdeaProjects\DocumentsStorage_v1\target\server\standalone\deployments
17:44:17,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0493: Jakarta Enterprise Beans subsystem suspension complete
17:44:17,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
17:44:17,808 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 7.0.0.Final (Apache CXF 4.0.0) 
17:44:17,961 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
17:44:17,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090/management
17:44:17,968 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10090
17:44:17,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 30.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 22.0.1.Final) started in 8592ms - Started 280 of 522 services (317 services are lazy, passive or on-demand) - Server configuration file in use: standalone.xml
```

But when the startup timeout finishes, I have

[image]

What is the problem? Thanks.

EDIT: I'm managing it with `wildfly-maven-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--
                     In produzione c'e' JBoss EAP 6.3 => JBoss AS 7.4.0.Final
                     ma tale release non e' disponibile nei repo Maven
                     quindi usiamo la versione piu' simile disponibile
                  -->
                <version>23.0.0.Final</version>
                <javaOpts>
                    -Xms64m
                    <!--                        -Xmx512m-->
                    <!--                        -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m-->
                    -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                    -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true
                    -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
                    -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
                    -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
                    -Djboss.server.config.dir=${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/configuration
                    <!--                        ${jacocoAgent}-->
                    <!--                        &lt;!&ndash;per eseguire il debug remoto rimuovere il commento dalla riga sottostante-->
                    <!--                            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=33333,server=y,suspend=y-->
                </javaOpts>
                <port>10090</port>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: Where does that failure come from?

Comment: Where is that failure message shown?

Comment: no failures, only timeout.

Comment: Please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the full server startup logs from IntelliJ IDEA run console and the IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Is not an IntelliJ problem

Comment: Assuming you have a service waiting for your app to be deployed, it looks like the folder "C:\Users\ActionICT-Motti\IdeaProjects\DocumentsStorage_v1\target\server\standalone\deployments" contains nothing to deploy, but it's just a guess

Comment: So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved running `wildfly:run` or `wildfly:deploy` maven task, that correctly logged the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all goals available [here](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/) for the `wildfly-maven-plugin`

If you want to run your server during dev, I guess the good mojo would be [`wildfly:dev`](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/dev-mojo.html)

> Starts a standalone instance of WildFly and deploys the application to the server. The deployment type myst be a WAR. Once the server is running, the source directories are monitored for changes. If required the sources will be compiled and the deployment may be redeployed.
>
> Note that changes to the POM file are not monitored. If changes are made the POM file, the process will need to be terminated and restarted.

You can also use the [`wildfly:start`](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/start-mojo.html) and [`wildfly:shutdown`](https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/shutdown-mojo.html) since start will do the following :

> Starts a standalone instance of WildFly Application Server. The purpose of this goal is to start a WildFly Application Server for testing during the maven lifecycle.

Comment: the dev task doesn't changes anything

Comment: Did you try upgrading to latest version of the plugin ? (4.2.2.Final)

Comment: yes, doesn't changes anything

Comment: So could you explain in more details what is the problem you're facing ?

Comment: THIS is the problem. For more details i need LOGGING that I DON'T HAVE

Comment: And by following this guide ? https://docs.wildfly.org/wildfly-maven-plugin/releases/4.2/execute-commands-example.html

Comment: With these options you could try adding the correct debug logger before it fails maybe